# enable to write to file inspite we remove all file permissions

Tags: files, permissions, root, chmod

something isn’t clearly for me
when I remove all permissions from file as chmod 000
I expected to get permissions denied when I write to file
but still I can write to file as the following example
can someone explain why?

```
[root@linux1 /tmp]# touch file
[root@linux1 /tmp]# ls -ltr file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:28 file
[root@linux1 /tmp]# chmod 000 file
[root@linux1 /tmp]# ls -ltr file
---------- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 15:28 file
[root@linux1 /tmp]# echo str > file
[root@linux1 /tmp]# more file
str
```

Comment: You can read this for some info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593752/who-can-access-a-file-with-octal-permissions-000-on-linux-unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without something like SELinux, `root` can always write to files; since you're running as `root` you can always write.

If you're not running as `root`, then the permissions apply; if `file` exists and is not writable, then `> file` or `>> file` will fail. If `file` does not exist, then it will be created if the parent directory is writable.

Comment: in my case echo str >> file isnt failed!

Comment: Even after running `chmod 000 file`?

Comment: YES I tested it and it rewrite

Comment: Also as an ordinary non-root user?

Comment: Ah but you're running as root, so you can always write...

Comment: you mean if I choose other user then I will get access denied?

Comment: `>` always opens and truncates the existing file if there is one.